# Cross-line regular expression search-and-replace in text editors

Tags: regex, text-editor

I'm looking for an open-source text editor which allows cross-line regular expression search and replace.

Thus, for example replacing \n with \n-------------------\n , and so introduce a dashed line between lines.

Or I could search for 08\nERROR and find

```
INFO 9329 21 June 2008
ERROR 3832 21 June 2008
```

UltraEdit has this feature, but that is a commercial product. I checked Notepad++, CrimsonEdit, etc., and did not find the cross-line search-and-replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing, Notepad++ did not support this -- but the latest version now does!

Answer (score 1):

Vim knows how to do this.

for instance, if you have:

```
if (a) {
    x++;
} else {
    x--;
}
```

then searching with `/;\n.*else` will find this:

```
       ;
} else
```

and doing this replace: `:s/;\n\(.*else\)/;\r//----\r\1/` will do:

```
if (a) {
    x++;
----
} else {
    x--;
}
```

(Note that I searched for the newline with `\n` but had to use `\r` in the replacement field)

Naturally, this will also work with your examples:

search for `08\nERROR` and find:

```
                    08
ERROR
```

Comment: Thanks, learning vim is useful. I tried this successfully. I have to admit I prefer GUI editors -- non-1337 though that is.